What J. Michael Straczynski screenplay was this 2006 Marvel comic referring to?
In the letters section of the 2006 comic Captain America #22, there is this congratulation for J. Michael Straczynski about an upcoming movie he wrote (JMS was also a writer at Marvel at that time):

We'd like to start out this month by congratulating J. Michael Straczynski, who recently sold an original screenplay for a big budget feature film to Ron Howard's Imagine Entertainment! We can't give away any of the details of the story, but filming is slated to begin as early as January, meaning the picture could be at your local multiplex by next winter! Nicely done, Joe--and remember, we knew you when!

What movie was this? Did it get produced and, if so, did its production match the timelines given?

It would appear that the comic book was referring to the movie Changeling, which was JMS's first feature film script. The timeline in the comic book blurb was a bit aggressive. According to that Wikipedia article, there was a delay because Ron Howard wanted to direct it himself, but he was busy on other projects. He ultimately decided to step down and let someone else direct.

In June 2006, Universal Studios and Howard's Imagine Entertainment bought the script for Howard to direct. The film was on a shortlist of projects for Howard after coming off the commercial success of The Da Vinci Code. In March 2007, Universal fast-tracked the production. When Howard chose Frost/Nixon and Angels & Demons as his next two directing projects, it became clear he could not direct Changeling until 2009. After Howard stepped down, it looked as if the film would not be made, despite admiration for the script in the industry. Howard and Imagine partner Brian Grazer began looking for a new director to helm the project; they pitched the film to Eastwood in February 2007, and he agreed to direct immediately after reading the script.

Filming actually began in October of 2007, and the movie premiered in May of 2008.

The 2008 film Changeling, a semi fictional crime thriller. His first original screenplay, purchased in June 2006.
It came out Nationwide October 2008, 2/3rd of a year later than they optimistically predicted. 
